# tab and Image View buttons

Tags: xcode

I'm a n00b at objective C and I am stuck on some coding for an App in Xcode.  The question is also posted in a variety of places but I can't find an answer.

The problem: Basically I want to change an image in a tab using an NSImageView connected to an object controller with two buttons in another tab.  The app runs with no problems see below:

```
.h class

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject {

    IBOutlet NSImageView *name;

}

- (IBAction)img1:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)img2:(id)sender;

@end


    .m class

#import mclass

@implementation AppDelegate

- (IBAction)img1:(id)sender {

    NSImage *img = [NSImage imageNamed:@"Image1.png"];
    [name setImage:img];
}

- (IBAction)img2:(id)sender
{
    NSImage *img = [NSImage imageNamed:@"Image2.png"];
    [name setImage:img];
}
```

It all connects no problem but the error message in Xcode says may not respond to setImage.  It seems there must be a very obvious solution but I just can't see it.  Some help is appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it's a UIImageView and UIImage not NSImageView and NSImage

Comment: problem solved must be app delegate!...was using an alternative object...many thanks anyway...nvrmind